# Transitions in vue3 work on slide in but not slide out

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, transition

I have this sample of code

Parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="cartToggle">Toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Child
      :visible="cartVisible"
      @update:visible="cartToggle"
      v-show="cartVisible"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import Child from "./Child.vue";

const cartVisible = ref(false);
const cartToggle = () => {
  cartVisible.value = !cartVisible.value;
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Child:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { toRefs, watchEffect, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  visible: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
});

const { visible } = toRefs(props);

const emit = defineEmits(["update:visible"]);

const hideCartBar = () => {
  emit("update:visible", false);
};

watchEffect(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = visible.value ? "hidden" : "auto";
  document.body.style.paddingRight = visible.value ? "15px" : "0px";
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
  document.body.style.paddingRight = "0px";
});
</script>

<template>
  <div class="cartbar">
    <div class="cartbar-wrapper">
      <transition name="fade">
        <div
          v-show="props.visible"
          class="cartbar-overlay"
          @click="hideCartBar"
        ></div>
      </transition>
      <transition name="slide">
        <div v-show="props.visible" class="cartbar-container">
          <div class="cartbar__header">
            <h2>Menu</h2>
            <span @click="hideCartBar" class="cursor-pointer">Close</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* transition */
/* transition */
.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.slide-enter-from,
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide-enter-to,
.slide-leave-from {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.slide-enter-active,
.slide-leave-active {
  transition: transform 500ms;
}
/* cartbar */
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cartbar-wrapper {
  transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  z-index: 1300;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: calc(4px * 9);
}

.cartbar-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cartbar-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: calc(4px * 7);
  background-color: #f4f2f1;
  color: #706b5f;
}
</style>
```

and the problem is, when I want to toggle the menu in .. it slides in fine, but it doesn't slide out ... plus - the overlay does not animate at all

what am I doing wrong?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue-3-glziy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-show="cartVisible"` on the Child removes the whole element before the out-transition even starts. But when simply removing the `v-show`, the `.cartbar-wrapper` will overlay the whole screen, making it impossible to press the button. You'll have to change the structure of the Child component so that it works without a container.

A simple solution would be to just remove the wrapper and put the `position:fixed` on the `.cartbar-container`, have a look a the [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: thx.. that's interesting .. is there a way I can wrap the transations inside any other parent div / wrapper so I can style i tproperly? or should I (generally speaking) keep them as a top level template elements? as you did ... thx man

Comment: btw any idea why the fade doesn't work still? not even in your example

Comment: Good question... whatever works, I guess? I usually look how libraries do it, like Vuetify's [navigation drawer](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/) does it [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/6da78af25d8790e4c6ac7d1e058bf3b037395f34/packages/vuetify/src/components/VNavigationDrawer/VNavigationDrawer.tsx#L215).

Comment: Found the problem with the fade, there was an `opacity:1` on the `.cartbar-overlay`, overriding the transition. Without it, it works as expected, check the updated the playground. Looks nice.

Comment: awesome :) thx a lot and thx for the tip to look at other libraries ;-)